# Displaying qml from c++ differs from what qmlscene shows

Tags: c++, qml, qt5

I'm try to run a basic program that displays a simple qml file through c++. The code for loading QQmlEngine etc looks like this:

```
#include <QQmlEngine>
#include <QQmlComponent>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQuickView>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlEngine engine;
    QQmlComponent component(&engine);
    QQuickWindow::setDefaultAlphaBuffer(true);
    component.loadUrl(QUrl("qrc:///qmlFiles/main.qml"));
    if ( component.isReady() )
        component.create();
    else
        qWarning() << component.errorString();
    QObject::connect(&engine, SIGNAL(quit()), QCoreApplication::instance(),SLOT(quit()));
    return app.exec();
}
```

and the qml (simplified) file is:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.0


ApplicationWindow
{
    width:800
    height:600
    //background: "white"

    visible:true

    function selectFile()
    {
        fileChooser.visible=true;

    }

    menuBar:MenuBar {

            Menu{
                    title:"File"
                    MenuItem{
                        text:"Choose File"
                        shortcut: "Ctrl+F"
                        onTriggered:{
                            selectFile();

                        }
                    }


                    MenuItem {
                        text:"Quit"
                        shortcut: "Ctrl+Q"
                        onTriggered: Qt.quit()
                    }
            }
    }
   FileDialog{
        id:fileChooser
        visible:false
        modality:Qt.WindowModal
        title:"Choose data file"
        onAccepted:{
            console.log(fileChooser.fileUrls)
            visible:false
        }
        onRejected:{
            console.log("Cancel")
            visible:false
        }
    }

}
```

When I run the file from terminal using qmlscene the displayed looks different than while running it from the c++ program.

My guess is that the C++ implementation is unable to use platform specific stuff (for example QFileDialog) and falls back to qml implementation of the stuff.

I guess I need to load the qml file differently, but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is some overriding or something with `QGuiApplication` .

Changed it to `QApplication` and looks as nice as in qmlscene.